# Logging into the Chat site

Tags: support, bug

I have not been able to log into the chat site for a few says now. All the tests that are done by the test thingie end up being ok, but... If I log out of all SE sites, then back into the math.SE site (using my Google ID) and then click onthe 'chat' link on top, I am taken to a page listing chat rooms but in which I am yet not logged in.

- If at this point I click on the 'Mathematics' room, I am taken there, still not logged in and the resulting page enters in an infinite loop, with the page reloading once and again.
- If instead I click on the 'log in' link at the top, I am taken to a page which tells me it is «Logging [me] in to the Stack Exchange chat…» but which after a few http requests just sits there. If I go to the «GlobalAuth test & help page», no problem is found. If I try to «log in via Stack Exchange Stack Exchange» then I am told that my Google OpenID is new to SE...

Clearing the cache, and/or removing all cookies does not help at all.

Ideas?

**Later...** I still cannot log in to chat...

Comment: "I have seen a chatroom without a moderator before, but I have never seen a moderator without a chatroom!" (Quote from *Mariano in Wonderland*.)

Comment: Just to make sure I'm understanding correctly: When you log into stackexchange.com (ignoring chat for a moment) with the same Google account you're using here on math.se, it tells you this OpenId is new to se.com?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Okay, we're looking at it. Please remember to @balpha me in the future, so I get a notification of your reply. Thanks!

Comment: I see you posted in chat recently, so I assume this has somehow resolved itself?

Comment: @balpha: not really. I logged into chat from a different computer. Both have exactly the same software (up to date Fedoras)