# Unable to log in to a chat room

Tags: support

when I try to enter into a chat room here, I am told by the browser to log in first (although it seems I'm logged in already, as my name is displayed on the stackexchange page, along with my user number : 15381).

When I try to log in via Stackexchange.com,  I am told my password is wrong, and in my e-mail I receive a password-reset link, which  does not work (the link is  https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/password-reset?token=72803688-78dd-4fd6-8efd-d8d8a289fe51, and the error message is "The requested resource (/dereferrer/) is not available.").

Somebody else experienced a similar problem : [Logging into the Chat site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3749/logging-into-the-chat-sitebu)

UPDATE : In answer to a comment below, I provide the following data :

OS : Mac OS X 10.4.10

Browser : Firefox

What happens on other machines : similar : I cannot log in and the password-reset link does not work

Comment: You'll likely want to provide some basic info: OS, internet browser, and whether you've tried this on multiple OS/browsers.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have a Stack Exchange OpenId (at least not attached to your account). You logged in to math.se using a different provider; click "my logins" on your [profile page](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/15381/ewan-delanoy) to see which one.